# How to convert datetime on a per user basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, utc

I have left my application.rb as it was and by default it is storing datetime in UTC.

Now at the UI level (for displaying only) I want to convert the datetime to the user specific timezone.

How can I convert the UTC datetime I get from postgresql and then convert it to the timezone that I will store for each user.

I want to make this conversion using the Offset so like: `-5:00 or +4:00`

Is it ok to do this, because I was just checking some locations and it seems their offset changes during the season.

E.g. virginia goes from UTC -5 to UTC -4 depending on the month.
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/richmond

```
If UTC is not consistant then I should just store the zone in the database for each user?
```

Comment: You can use Time.current...check this out - http://apidock.com/rails/Time/current/class

Answer (score 1):

When I made an app with scheduling events, I had to add timezones to the User model to offset their scheduling.

When I recorded the offset, I used the following code:

```
<%= time_zone_select "user", 
                     "timezone", 
                     ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, 
                     {default: "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"},
                     {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Because Rails has [time zones built into their ActiveSupport model.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) You could use `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all` if you wanted users to be global.

Here's some info on [time_zone_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select)

Then depending on how you use it, you can just set

```
Time.zone = current_user.timezone unless current_user.nil?
```

or something similar in your `application.rb` file.

UPDATE

I personally used it to set the timezone in the controller on the only 2 actions where it was necessary.

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @pending = @user.share_events.where("time > ?", DateTime.now.in_time_zone(@user.timezone))
  @complete = @user.share_events.where("time <= ?", DateTime.now.in_time_zone(@user.timezone))
end

def new
  @user = current_user
  Time.zone = @user.timezone
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @share_event = ShareEvent.new
end
```

Comment: the application.rb should stay UTC, only when I display things in the UI should I be converting the datetime to the user specific timezone.

Comment: Can I see how you actually converted the UTC timezone that is from your db to the user specific?

Comment: Answer updated to show two ways I used UTC timezone.